# How to define a math command that displays a variable in a specific font?

Tags: fonts, math-mode

How to define a math command that displays a variable in a specific font? E.g. usage `\MyMathCommand{P}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
\newcommand{\MyMathCommand}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
```

which would print the variable in **boldface** (perhaps typical of matrix or vector notation). There is also `\mathit` (for *italic* math) and `\mathsf` (for sans serif fonts). These can be mixed in some fonts. You may be interested also in `\mathcal` (for calligraphy-style letters, perhaps used in set notation) or something else altogether.

If you wish for this command to work in either text or math mode, you can use:

```
\newcommand{\MyMathCommand}[1]{\ensuremath{\mathbf{#1}}}
```